# Embedding dimension of smooth affine variety of dimension $d$ , over an infinite perfect field, is $2d+1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, regular-rings

Let $k$ be an infinite [perfect field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field).

Let $R$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra of Krull dimension $d$ such that $R$ is [regular](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ring).

Then is it true that there exists a surjective $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x_1,\dots,x_{2d+1}]\to R $ ?

Comment: Do you know how to do this when $k$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: @Mohan: unfortunately, I don't ... :-(

Comment: One way is to look at the secant variety in some large embedding and clearly it has dimension $2d+1$. So, if the embedding dimension is larger, you can project from a point outside the secant variety preserving the embedding.